# Problems creating a looped animation

Tags: animation

I'm trying to animate a fish swimming around a bowl.

At the end of the loop, I copied the keyframes from Frame 1 & pasted them at the end, so that at the end the object is in the same position & orientation as the beginning.

Strangely, this makes the animated object do a quick 360 degree spin just before the last keyframe.  I wasn't expecting that.  Does anyone have any clue why that happens?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at your Z roation in your graph editor. I bet it goes one way, and suddenly the other way at the end.

Your rotated your fish arround in one direction. But the first key is not in that continuity, you effectively ask your fish to rotate back in a short amount of time. You should add 360 degrees to the last rZ keyframe.